# Сравнение класса объектов

Tags: java, объекты, сравнение

Есть 2 объекта. нужно узнать одинаковый ли у них класс

Comment: Обычно  это решается через `object.getClass().getName()`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static boolean  isEqualsClass(Object obj, Object obj1){
    return obj.getClass().equals(obj1.getClass());
}
```

Использование:

```
Object obj = new String();
Object obj1 =new String();

System.out.println(isEqualsClass(obj, obj1));
```